# The Variance of sum of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, variance, covariance

I am working on a statistics problem that involves finding the variance of two dependent variables being added together.

The question is:

Suppose that on your morning commute you must pass through two
traffic lights: the time $X$ you spend stopped at the first light has a mean of $20$ seconds and a standard deviation of $5$ seconds, while the time $Y$ you spend stopped at the second light has a mean of $30$ seconds and a standard deviation of $10$ seconds. Also, suppose
that the correlation between $X$ and $Y$ is $p = .3$. What is the variance
of the total time $X + Y$ stopped at the traffic lights?

My incorrect attempt at solving it:

I found the covariance as $15$. Then, because the variables are not independent, I thought that I should use the $E(X^2) - (E(X))^2$ formula. This yields $E(X^2) + 2E(XY) + E(Y^2) - (50^2)$. Then, this becomes 400 + $2(615) + 900 - 2500 = 30$.

However, the solution sheet says that the answer is $V(X) + 2\text{Cov}(X,Y) + V(Y) = 5^2 + 2(15) + 10^2 = 155$.

Why is my solution incorrect?

Comment: You seem to falsely think that for a normal random variable $X$ that $\mathrm E(X^2)=\mathrm E(X)^2$. I.e, $\mathrm E(Y^2)\neq 50$.

Comment: It seems that your derivation $E(X^2)+2E(XY)+E(Y^2)-(50)^2$ isn't correct. I believe you forgot to plug in $X+Y$ for the second expectation.

Comment: @K.defaoite: I do not think that any of the rvs involved is normal, since waiting times are usually non-negative.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow thought they were normal. But, my point still stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\mathbb E[X+Y]=\mathbb E[X]+\mathbb E[Y]=20+30$. Hence, we get
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{Var}(X+Y)&=\mathbb E[(X+Y-20-30)^2]\\
&=\mathbb E[(X-20)^2]+\mathbb E[(Y-30)^2]+2\mathbb E[(X-20)(Y-30)]\\
&=5^2+10^2+2\cdot 0.3\cdot 5\cdot 10,
\end{aligned}
using the definition of the variance and of Pearson's product-moment coefficient.